# Cannot divide two NSNumbers in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, divide

I have two NSNumbers that I want to divide, but in the last line of the code I get the error: "Cannot invoke '/' with an argument list of type '(@Ivalue NSNumber,@Ivalue NSNumber)'"

```
var firstnumber: NSNumber = object["numberone"] as NSNumber
var secondnumber: NSNumber = object["numbertwo"] as NSNumber
var calculated: NSNumber = firstnumber / secondnumber
```

Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSNumber is an object which holds a value that can be retreived as different types by using its properties such as `floatValue`, `integerValue` and so on. [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html)

So by doing `nsnumber1 / nsnumber2` would be like doing `uiview1 / uiview2`

Answer (score 2):

I guess your number1 and number2 are Float or Double, take Float as example:

```
var caculated = firstnumber.floatValue / secondnumber.floatValue as NSNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need perform division on `NSNumber` you need to use `NSDecimalNumber`.

So you need perform division as follows:

```
let object = ["numberone" : "33", "numbertwo" : "33"]
var firstnumber: NSDecimalNumber =  NSDecimalNumber(string: object["numberone"])
var secondnumber: NSDecimalNumber =  NSDecimalNumber(string: object["numbertwo"])
var calculated: NSDecimalNumber = firstnumber.decimalNumberByDividingBy(secondnumber)
```